# Replace Element in JSON with a element in a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON

```
[{"id":7,"serial":"7bc530","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null},
{"id":8,"serial":"4a18d27","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null},
{"id":9,"serial":"f30ef","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null},
{"id":10,"serial":"9e6d","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null},
{"id":11,"serial":"4d8665a3","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null},
{"id":12,"serial":"4fe1457","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null}]
```

and I have this JSON

```
{"computers":[{"id":"7bc530","name":"Dell","description":"Dell"},
{"id":"f30ef","name":"HP","description":"HP"},
{"id":"9e6d","name":"Compaq","description":"Compaq"},
{"id":"4d8665a3","name":"Toshiba","description":"Toshiba"},
{"id":"4fe1457","name":"Asus","description":"Asus"},
{"id":"4a18d27","name":"Acer","description":"Acer"}]}
```

I want to replace the "serial" element in the first JSON with the "Description" in this one. The reason why I need it in one JSON is that I am using a DataTable and I can only pass one JSON in.

I'm not sure how I can do this in Javascript / JQuery?

Comment: i'm guessing serial in 1 is id in 2, so loop through the first one referencing the second one to populate the first one.

Comment: are both arrays in the same order?

Comment: tip: iterate over the first one and use the value of the serial key to find the entry in the second one ... I leave the implementation up to you to not intervene @undefined 's question ;-)

Comment: I've tried a few things but I'm not that good with javascript / jquery syntax to have it actually work properly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this without any jQuery by setting up small function:

([see the demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevenschobert/BB8UU/))

```
function replaceSerial (data1, data2) {
    var descs = {}, computers = data2['computers'], final = data1;

    for (var i = 0; i < computers.length; i++ ) {
        descs[computers[i]['id']] = computers[i]['description'];
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        final[i]['serial'] = descs[data1[i]['serial']];
    }

    return final;
}
```

Then just save your two pieces of JSON into variables and invoke the function:

```
var json1, json2, mergedJson;

json1 = // DATA IN FIRST JSON;
json2 = // DATA IN SECOND JSON;

mergedJson = replaceSerial (json1, json2);
```

Comment: What do I do if my "data1" json has no name? The name "computers" is available on the second but none for the first.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you be more specific, or post an example? You can assign a "name" to your json by assigning it to a variable. JSON is by-nature valid javascript. The first piece of JSON you posted is an array `[]`, and the second you posted is an object `{}`.

Comment: Hey please let me know, how to merge two JSON object into one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first object is called `to` and the second object is called `from`

```
// Iterate over each entry in to
to.forEach(function(value) {
    // In each iteration find elements in from where the id is the same
    // as the serial of the current value of to
    var description = from.computers.filter(function(element){
        if (element.id == value.serial) return true;
    });
    // Copy description of first found object in the description property of
    // the current object
    value.description = description[0].description;
    // Unset serial?
    delete value.serial;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7P9dk/1/)

Comment: should note that `forEach` not available in all browsers such as IE < 9

Comment: And in some browsers there is no JavaScript such as lynx ;)